# Which is preferred for liquid atomization - gas & liquid shear or liquid & liquid shear?

Tags: fuel, engine-design, spacecraft-development, injector

For generating a spray of droplets, liquid need to be disintegrated/atomized through shear forces.

Typical injectors in IC engines and aircraft use shear between gas & liquid at the phase interface to atomize the liquid.

Will liquid-liquid shear be as effective in atomization as gas-liquid shear? Note: interest in liquid-liquid shear is important in bi-liquid injectors where fuel and oxygen are in liquid form

Comment: That should atomize the sheared liquid just fine... suspending it in still unatomized shearing liquid. Not sure if that's what you want, especially that the volume of the shearing medium will need to be much larger than of the sheared one. At least with a gas you can retain similar mass proportions (large volume+low density).

Comment: @SF. - any reference you can help me with that shows/discusses that "... the volume of the shearing medium will need to be much larger than of the sheared one."..I will greatly appreciate it. That will be necessary for convincing my colleagues at my lab!

Comment: @SF - actually the second liquid used for shearing is also moving and must also undergo atomisation. The second liquid is not still

Comment: The shearing is caused by a continuous stream of the gas/liquid. To atomize that you'd need a third stream - which you'd then need to atomize with fourth and so on. Just movement is insufficient, you need a fast, strong stream of the atomizing medium at correct angle to the opening of the nozzle of the atomized medium. If you just float loose atomized droplets instead of a solid stream you're not shearing anything. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomizer_nozzle